# Sqlite3 Module in Python far Slower SELECT than in Shell

Tags: python, sql, shell, sqlite

I am using the sqlite3 module in Python but am finding it incredibly slow for a certain SELECT query relative to running the query in sqlite3 in a command shell. I will start off by saying that both versions are the same 3.7.17.

My query is

```
SELECT r.ID, r.Date FROM my_table r
WHERE
r.Date IN (SELECT Date FROM my_table WHERE ID = r.ID GROUP BY Date LIMIT 2);
```

The Python code is

```
con = lite.connect(path_to_database)
cur = con.cursor()

with con:
    cur.execute(sql_query)
```

where `sql_query` is a string variable containing the initial query.

I'm assuming the problem is in optimising the `IN` subquery.

Performance details: `my_table` contains 167000 records, the query in the shell takes ~10 seconds, the query in Python takes > 5 minutes (I stopped it when it got this far).

Currently as it is table creation I am just copying and pasting code into the shell as a workaround, how can I fix this so that I can run the query from Python?

**ADDITION**

When I run `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` I get the following

Shell:

```
0           0           0           SCAN TABLE PIT_10_Days AS r (~500000 rows)
0           0           0           EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 1
1           0           0           SEARCH TABLE PIT_10_Days USING AUTOMATIC C
1           0           0           USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Python:

```
0           0           TABLE PIT_10_Days AS r 
0           0           TABLE PIT_10_Days
```

I'm not sure if the difference is a problem with getting `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` in Python or if it is actually the problem itself.

Comment: Can you show us the code in Python you use for the query? Also sample data for testing would help.

Comment: Hi Jan, the code itself its quite long but basically goes `con = sqlite3.connect(path_to_database); cur = con.curor(); with con: cur.execute(the_above_query)`

Comment: Can you verify that there aren't any `PRAGMA` statements executed in the shell?

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @rwolst Please, add the way you call the query into your question, it will be more readable. Realize, that you talk about the same query being performed in shall and from Python having different execution times. As you show us only the query, we have no idea about context, which is likely to be the key of the problem.

Comment: @rwolst One idea - consider making smaller example and run it from Python and console. As you say, that Python call is too slow and you have stopped it, it is also possible, it got stuck in some never ending loop and it had nothing to do with SQLite.

Comment: Ok, will do. Note that I have uploaded the explain for both queries as they differ slightly. Python: http://dumptext.com/053XxTOc , Shell: http://dumptext.com/mIlRaK4u. In this case `my_table` is `PIT_10_Days`.

Comment: I debugged and made sure the program hit the sqlite function call so it is not stuck in a loop I don't think.

Comment: Show the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`.

Comment: I've added the output of explain query plan to the question.

Comment: I think we need to see exactly how you build your sql_query variable in python, the plan could be affected by exactly how you create the text - for instance I have had cases where because the literal string is unicode, the SQL engine treated it very differently when it executed.

Comment: Ok, Ill have a look back at the code. In the end I just wrote the query to a temporary file and executed it using system as opposed to the sqlite3 module, so if anyone else has this problem that is always an option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to be so late, but I have only now found this question.
Unfortunately I have no idea why the sqlite3 module behaves differently than the shell but
you could try to avoid the correlated query from the first place. I'm not sure whether it always does what you want anyway because you do not order the results in your subquery.

I suppose you want the two latest dates for each ID?
Try this:

```
SELECT r.ID AS ID, max( r.Date ) AS Date
 FROM my_table AS r
 GROUP BY r.ID

UNION

SELECT r.ID, max( r.Date )
  FROM 
      my_table AS r
      JOIN ( 
        SELECT ID,
               max( Date ) AS Date
          FROM my_table
         GROUP BY ID) AS maxDat
      ON
      r.ID = maxDat.ID AND
      r.Date != maxDat.Date
 GROUP BY r.ID;
```

It selects the IDs together with their latest Date.
Then it unifies this result with a similar selection from a table where the actual latest date is taken out so that you will get the second latest date. If you need more than the latest two dates this will get pretty cumbersome, but for two dates only it should be okay and probably much faster.